# how to generate tensorflow matrix with first of few columns as 1 and the rest as 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

Given a list `len_list` of the number of ones for the vectors, e.g.:

```
[1]
[3] 
[2] 
[1]
```

where the shape of `len_list` now is `(4, 1)`

And given the number of columns of the vector, e.g. `vec_dim = 5`.

I'd like to generate a tensor with the first of few columns as 1 and the rest as 0. 
For example, a matrix with shape of `(4, 5)` as:

```
[1 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0]
```

How to do so?

I understand I could generate this matrix with iteration.

But in my case, the batch size is not set, i.e. the shape for `len_list` is `(None, 1)`, I have to feed the placeholder with batch size to fulfill this function. Thus, how could I generate a tensor with shape `(None, vec_dim)`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `tf.sequence_mask()`  which returns a mask tensor representing the first N positions of each cell.

Below is the code to get the output as you mentioned above.

```
len_list = np.array([1,3,2,1])

mask = tf.sequence_mask(len_list, maxlen=5, dtype=tf.int32) #maxlen set to 5 to generate (4,5) matrix.
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

If you don't want to set the `max_length` explicitly, you can instead take maximun number from the `len_list` as below.

```
len_list = np.array([1,3,2,1])
maxlen = tf.reduce_max(len_list) #3 in this case
mask = tf.sequence_mask(len_list, maxlen=maxlen, dtype=tf.int32)
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: @Megan Dawn - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if the above answer satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Already done that, while --------- 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'